# Why do I get timeout error doing an api call using python with requests library if with curl works well?

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest, curl, python-requests

I trying to make a simple call to an api. With this instruction of curl in the terminal works fine, I get the json file back

```bash
curl -X GET "https://my.domain.com/api/product/?name=product" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "x-api-key: 02987eafdeef73450982734"
```

I trying to make the same call in python with the requests library, but I always receive an timeout error:

```python
base_url = 'https://my.domain.com'
timeout = 10
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': '02987eafdeef73450982734'
}

results = requests.get(
    f'{base_url}/api/product/?name=product',
    headers=headers,
    timeout=timeout
) # a headers param exists
```

Can you see the reason? Am I doing anything wrong? Am I  missing anything?

Comment: Just checking right, but you do know you are using a different API key in both requests?

Comment: Ah yes, Thanks @gna. I wanted to make it up the key and I forgot to copypaste the string into the second example. The problem must be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not setting the api url well in python. I was not using the same as I was posting in my question.

Enabling the verbose mode helped me to find the error, in the request library. This way:

```
import logging
import http.client as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

# request GET call
```

To enable the verbose mode in curl I just needed to add the `-v` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the default timeout of `curl` is 5 minutes ([AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526226/what-is-the-default-timeout-value-for-curl)).
My first suggestion would be to increase the timeout of the request using the `requests` package to 5 minutes (`timeout = 5 * 60`) and see if the request succeeds.

To answer your question directly, the requests look sufficiently similar.
You might also want to try making the request using a GUI client (e.g. [Hoppscotch](https://hoppscotch.io/)); it'll tell you the response time e.t.c.

If you only see the timeout-style errors from `requests`, try different Python libraries for making HTTP requests: it might help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried that and now I got another error: `502 Bad Getaway (nginx)`. So it must be doing something different from python. I will try with another library

Comment: Ah ! And I have tried from the website you posted, Hoppscotch, but I don't get any result. It says "Could not send request". Even if I import the curl command that works well from my debian terminal :/

Comment: Ah ! If I try this from python works well, but I would like to do it in a more correct way than running commands on the terminal directly :/ `import os
os.system('curl -X GET "https://demo.vottun.com/api/product/?name=product_name" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-api-key: 02987eafdeef73450982734"')`

Comment: Wow. Finally I found the error. It was that I was not setting the api url okay in the python call. However, in Hoppscotch is still not working. Anyway, I don't know if I should remove the question. What helped me to find the error was to enable the verbose mode